# How to create a Hyper-V Internal network

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, virtualization, hyper-v

I have a Windows 2008 server running multiple Hyper-V guests.  I want to create a Hyper-V "Internal" network.  So far, I cannot get anything to communicate.

1. I created the Internal network adapter in the Hyper-V manager
2. I assigned each VM's network adapter to the internal network adapter
3. I assigned an IP address to the host (10.1.0.1) with no default gateway (since it also has an external network card with a gateway)
4. I assigned each guest VM an IP (10.1.0.x) with 10.1.0.1 (host) as the gateway
5. I installed the Routing and Remote Access roll on the host

The problem is that neither the host or the guests and ping any other IP on the network.  I have no communication at all between any of the guests.  The guests in question are Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise, standard install (not Core).

What am I missing to get the host/vms to communicate via the internal network adapter?

Comment: I should note I did extensive searching on this topic.  The only page I found even close was : http://www.infotechguyz.com/server2008/hypervrouting.html.  Even follow those steps exactly didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the VMs can't ping even between themselves, then something is definitely broken here, and it's not related to the RRAS service running on the host; regardless of their default gateway's behaviour, machines placed on the same network and with proper IP configuration ***should*** be able to talk at least between themselves.

Did you try disabling Windows Firewall on the guests?

Also, as per Greg Askew's suggestion, I'd try removing RRAS on the host; maybe it's messing up something with Hyper-V networking.

Comment: I think you're right.  He may want to remove RRAS and verify that there is connectivity between the guests, then determine if RRAS is required.

Comment: Agreed, maybe RRAS is messing things up on the host. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: I disabled the firewall and all of a sudden it started working fine.  I didn't do that before because I didn't have issues with the firewall when using an External network.  Now I'm just trying to get NAT working so the VMs can get access to the internet through a new VM I'm setting up for RRAS/DNS/DHCP.

Comment: "When in doubt, disable Windows Firewall." (TM)